# Laurent Series of $f(z)=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}-\frac{5}{z-4}$ that converges at $z=1$ in powers of $z-2$

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, laurent-series

> I am trying to find the Laurent series of, $$f(z)=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}-\frac{5}{z-4},$$ in powers of $z-2$ that converges at $z=1$.

My attempt:

I think our radius for convergence is $|z-2|<2$. Now,
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}-\frac{5}{z-4} \\
&=-2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right)+\frac{5}{4-z} \\
&=-2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{4+(z-2)}\right)+\frac{5}{2-(z-2)} \\
&=-2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{4+(z-2)}\right)+\frac{5}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(z-2)^n}{2^n}
\end{align}
I am stuck at this point. $-2\frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{4+(z-2)}\right)$ appears not to be convergent in the region $|z-2|<2$. It certainly converges in the region $2<|z-2|<4$, but this is not where $z=1$ is located. I am very confused.

---

**further attempt**

Using the information from a related post ([Finding a series for $f(z)=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2989696/finding-a-series-for-fz-frac2z22)), I believe the correct Laurent series is $$5\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(z-2)^n}{2^{n+1}}-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n(z-2)^{n-1}}{4^{n+1}}.$$
Is this correct? The answer that I have found in the book states the correct series is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left((-1)^n\frac{2(n+1)}{4^{n+3}}+\frac{5}{2^{n+1}}\right)(z-2)^n.$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that\begin{align}\frac1{4+(z-2)}&=\frac14\frac1{1+\frac{z-2}4}\\&=\frac14\left(1-\frac{z-2}4+\frac{(z-2)^2}{4^2}-\frac{(z-2)^3}{4^3}+\cdots\right)\\&=\frac14-\frac{z-2}{4^2}+\frac{(z-2)^2}{4^3}-\frac{(z-2)^3}{4^4}+\cdots\end{align}and that this series converges in the region $\lvert z-2\rvert<4$.

Comment: Yes, I have noted this. But does this converge in the region where $z=1$ (which is what the question asks)?

Comment: @Bell Since $\lvert1-2\rvert=1<4$, yes.

Comment: Okay. I was considering the regions $|z-2|<2, \ 2<|z-2|<4$ and $|z-2|>4$. Because $z=1$ lies within $|z-2|<2$, I was thinking that the series could only converge for $|z-2|<2$. This is incorrect?

Comment: @Bell The domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{-2,4\}$. So, the Taylor series of $f$ centered at $2$ converges in the larges open disk centered at $2$ and contained in the domain, which is the disk centered at $2$ and with radius $2$. And $1$ belongs to that disk.

Comment: Okay. So if $A$ is the disk $|z-2|<2$, then this inequality holds $\forall z\in A$. I don't quite get why a $z\in A$ also satisfies the disk $|z-2|<4$ and hence the annulus $2<|z-2|<4$. Is this because it is the largest disk centered at $2$?

Comment: @Bell I only wrote that a certain series converges when $\lvert z-2\rvert<4$, but what I did doesn't take into account that $-\frac5{z-4}$ part of $f$.

Comment: @Bell Is everything clear now?

Comment: and we can check this by $|z-2|<4$? e.g. if $z=1.5$, then would this series also converge as $|1.5-2|=0.5<4$?

Comment: @Bell Actually, $\lvert1.5-2\rvert=0.5$, but yes.