# Finding a series for $f(z)=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2}$

Tags: proof-verification, power-series

I am trying to find a series for $$f(z)=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2},$$ that's convergent for $|z-2|<4$.

I have found that 
\begin{align}
f(z)&=\frac{2}{(z+2)^2} \\
&=-2 \ \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{z+2}\right) \\
&=-2 \ \frac{d}{dz}\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-2}{4}}\right)\right) \\
&=-2 \ \frac{d}{dz}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{(z-2)^n}{4^{n+1}}\right) \\
&=-2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^n\frac{n(z-2)^{n-1}}{4^{n+1}}.
\end{align}
I am unsure if this result is correct.

Comment: Your doubts would be quite obvious because term by term differentiation of infinite series is possible for uniform convergence which is guaranteed by dominated convergence theorem

Comment: It looks fine to me.

Comment: @Manthanein So deriving in the way that I did is invalid?

Comment: Not always,  only in some cases it becomes invalid. I haven't tried the theorem in your case but my intuition says it could be correct.

Comment: There are some indications that makes it look right, which are worth noting. (i) The coefficients go as $4^{-n}$, or more precisely $\limsup |a_n|^{1/n}=1/4$, the reciprocal of the radius of convergence (which is early 4); (ii) notice the extra $n$ in the numerator, indicative of a double pole at the singularity, again correct. Of course this doesn't make your answer right, but whenever you derive something like this, doing a "smell test" on it is often sensible.

Comment: Okay, thanks. This is part of a larger question (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2932792/laurent-series-of-fz-frac2z22-frac5z-4-that-converges-at-z-1). I'd very much like someone to confirm my Laurent series, as the answer that has been provided to me does not make sense (and does not concur with the result shown above).